# Poincaré-Bendixson theorem, periodic solutions/periodic orbits

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

According to my book (Hsu: ODE), a solution $\phi(t)$ to the system $x' = f(x)$ that is bounded for all $t \geq 0$ satisfies one of:

1) $\omega(\phi)$ contains an equilibrium, or

2) either $\phi(t)$ is periodic or $\omega(\phi)$ is a periodic orbit.

My question is: what is the difference between the solution being periodic and the limit set $\omega(\phi)$ being a periodic orbit?

Comment: To me seems consistent. As a limit cycle has a periodic solution (once it attains the limit cycle) and the set of points in the phase space maps a closed orbit. (At least from my physicists point of view).

Comment: A solution spiralling in towards a limit cycle is an example of a non-periodic solution whose omega-limit set (i.e., the limit cycle) is a periodic solution.

Comment: Imagine solutions in polar coordinates $(r(t),\theta(t))$ with $\theta(t)=t$ and $r(t)=1-(1-r_0)e^{-t}$, then, for $r_0\ne1$, the solution never meets the unit circle, is not periodic, and has the unit circle as limit set, and the limit set $r=1$ is indeed a periodic orbit.

Comment: Oh so an example of a limit set as a periodic orbit is basically a function who tends to a periodic function in the limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in comments, a non-periodic solution whose limit set is a periodic orbit is something spiraling toward a periodic orbit (either from the inside or from outside). An example of such a system is 
$$\begin{split} x' &= x\cos(x^2+y^2) - y \\ y' &= y\cos(x^2+y^2)+x\end{split}$$
The plot below (courtesy of [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=stream+plot+%5Bx*cos%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%29-y%2C+y*cos%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%29%2Bx%5D+x+from+-2+to+2%2C+y+from+-2+to+2)) shows two periodic orbits, one of which is attracting (and is the limit set for many non-periodic solutions) and the other one is repelling.

[image]

This system has infinitely many periodic orbits which are concentric circles, alternating between attracting and repelling.